# Access image using url on aws ec2 server

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I'm working on the AWS EC2 server on which I saved a image on a specific path `/var/www/html/uploads/imageName.jpg` using FileZila. I want to access that image using url. How can I do that? I have both access read and write in that directory.

below are the security groups

```
 HTTP           TCP  80     MyIP
 CustomTCPRule  TCP  8080   MyIP
SSH             TCP  22     MYIP
```

Comment: What do you mean? You want to setup a web server for that?

Comment: I have a image on server of aws ec2 on the given path I just want to access it. How can I do that @Marcin

Comment: Like using curl?, `curl http://<ip-address>/uploads/imageName.jpg`?

Comment: @Marcin when I hit that url then this will show me `Website not available` reason for this message is `We found the website's address but were unable to connect to the web server.`

Comment: Sorry, you need to be more specific.  What are its security groups? Do you use Load balancer? What are its settings? Do you use custom or default VPC and more.

Comment: @Marcin I update my question with the security groups

Comment: @Marcin I'm not using load balancer right now

Comment: Does you web application work if you ssh into it and `curl` from the inside?

Comment: @Marcin in ssh I'm getting `curl: (7) Failed to connect to IP port 80: Connection timed out`

Comment: So your web server is down. Check it logs to try to start it again.

Comment: @Marcin Can you please tell me how can I do that

Comment: @Marcin I enable all the ports `8080, 80, 22` with anywhere source. Now I'm getting `curl: (7) Failed to connect to IP port 80: Connection refused`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to access information from a computer via HTTP, then the computer needs to be running a web server.

If it *is* running a web server, test it by logging into the instance and running:

```
curl localhost
```

If this fails, then something is wrong with your web server.